# creating a 2d unordered_map C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a 2D unordered_map that looks like:

`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, double>>`

So first, I implemented the inner unordered_graph by doing:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, double> *inner = new  
           std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, double>>()
inner->insert(std::make_pair("X", 0));
```

Then, I tried to make the outer unordered_map by doing

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, double> *outer =   
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, double>>()
outer->insert("X", inner);
```

but it gives me an error saying that`no matching function for call to insert`

Comment: The one you call `inner` is actually the same as the outer mapping. *And* it's not compilable, as you're missing some closing `>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `insert` wrong here:

```
outer->insert("X", inner);
```

It expects a value_type i.e. std::pair.  You're passing two arguments instead of one, so you need to do `make_pair()` on those arguments, plus you need to pass a value, so `*inner` instead of `inner` which is a pointer.

Once this is all said and done, you will probably be better off with a different data structure, as a hash table of hash tables is usually not the most efficient.

Comment: +1 , particularly for the advice on a different structure. Hash tables of hash tables is usually pointless since you can generally just use a single hash table and a `std::pair<key1,key2>` as a key type (which is hashable, of course). Unless you need to toss around, assign, etc *instances* or *references-to* the inner map object, it may be a worthy alternative.